# How do I remove first character in specific column using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have file with the next structure:

```
999963803|081439403|FFF|33
999964211|081823904|FFF|33
999970948|081765738|FFF|33
999971835|081736346|FFF|33
999972780|082127527|FFF|33
```

I need remove the first character in the second column, 
I try with `sed  "s/|.1|/^.\(.*\)/\1/" my_file.txt`, but doesn't work, the result must be:

```
999963803|81439403|FFF|33
999964211|81823904|FFF|33
999970948|81765738|FFF|33
999971835|81736346|FFF|33
999972780|82127527|FFF|33
```

Comment: Will the number of characters in each column always be static?  Ie in your current example column 1 has 9, will it always have 9 characters?

Comment: Not an answer because Perl wasn't mentioned, but `perl -ne 's/(?<=\|)\d//; print' in.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple `awk`:

```
awk -F"|" '{OFS="|"}$2=$2*1' file
```

`OFS` defines the output field separator. `$2=$2*1` just multiplies the second field with `1`; the leading zero disappears.

Answer (score 4):

with awk:

```
 awk -F"|" '{print $1"|"substr($2,2)"|"$3"|"$4}' <test
```

Answer (score 3):

With POSIX sed:

```
sed -e 's/[^|]\([^|]*|\)/\1/2' <file
```

The regex `[^|][^|]*|` meaning one or more sequences of characters except `|`, so it will match each fields, except the last one, you need `[^|][^|]*$` to match the last field. `2` modifier made `s`ubstitute command only do the substitution for the second match, which is the second field.

With GNU or BSD sed, you can simplified syntax to:

```
sed -E 's/[^|]([^|]*|)/\1/2' <file
```

([sed -E will become standard in next POSIX version](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528))

Comment: Hmm... This is a good solution. As someone trying to get better with Regex/Sed usage, would you mind breaking down the regex? I think i get it, but would help to know how it actually fits together.

Comment: @Gravy: Yeah, I added the explanation to my answer.

Comment: Why the downvoter?

Answer (score 2):

Why so complex?

It is the first character after the first `|` so...
`sed <filename -e 's/|./|/'`
... should work.

That is, find the first `|` and include the character after it, replace with just `|`.

e.g:

```
$ sed <my_file.txt -e 's/|./|/'
999963803|81439403|FFF|33
999964211|81823904|FFF|33
999970948|81765738|FFF|33
999971835|81736346|FFF|33
999972780|82127527|FFF|33
```

Note: add `/g` at the end to make it replace all occurrences, not just the first.

Comment: ... and similarly, to remove the first char in the third column `sed 's/|./|/2' infile` and so on...